# When to surround props with curly braces in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

In the official tutorial, this code shows up:

```
    <TextInput
      style={{height: 40}}
      placeholder="Type here to translate!"
      onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})}
    />
```

Why do we surround `height` with curly braces but not `placeholder`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
placeholder="Type here to translate!"
```

and

```
placeholder={'Type here to translate!'}
```

are equivalent. You can also write it like this, to visually separate it better:

```
placeholder={
  'Type here to translate!'
}
```

Knowing that, you can pass **almost** anything to react props, like an object:

```
style={
  {height: 40}
}
```

Which, written inline, results in what you encountered:

```
style={{height: 40}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're surrounding height with curly braces because you're passing javascript to the style and onChangeText props. Strings can be passed literally where as javascript needs to be surrounded by curly braces. It's part of the JSX syntax

Answer (score 0):

Height is a property of a JavaScript object, and that object is being passed to an **option**, *placeholder* is a an option for the TextView component.